# Norm of the derivatives of a polynomial

Tags: calculus

Let $M$ be an integer bigger than $2$, and

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{j=2}^{M}f_j+\frac{(x-\beta_2)(x-\beta_3)\cdots\cdots(x-\beta_
M)}{(\beta_1-\beta_2)(\beta_1-\beta_3)\cdots(\beta_1-\beta_{M})}(\beta_1^{2013}-1)$$

find $(\beta_1\,,\beta_2\,,\ldots, \beta_M)$ which $1<\beta_1<\beta_2<\cdots< \beta_M<2$ such that  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{M-1}|f^{(k)}(0)|\leq 2$,
where

$$f_j=\frac{(x-\beta_1)(x-\beta_2)\cdots(x-\beta_{j-1})(x-\beta_{j+1})\cdots(x-\beta_
M)}{(\beta_j-\beta_1)(\beta_j-\beta_2)\cdots(\beta_j-\beta_{j-1})(\beta_j-\beta_{j+1})\cdots(\beta_j-\beta_
M)}(\beta_j^{2013}-1),$$

and $f^{(k)}(0)$ is the $k$ order derivatives. i.e., $f$ is the Lagrange interpolation polynomial.

Comment: You lack question part :)

Comment: my question is to find $\beta_i$ such that the norm of the coefficients of the Lagrange interpolation polynomial f is smaller than 2.